# Create custom Database Connection in Django

Tags: python, django, arangodb

I am creating a project in DJango where I want to use a mixture of `MySQL` and `ArangoDB`. I am creating an API based on `DJango REST Framework`.

### The Process for ArangoDB

1. User calls an API and request enters in the VIEW
2. View validates the request.data via `serializers`
3. If data is valid, `.save()` is called which saves the data in `ArangoDB`.
4. I won't use Models as there is no schema (that's why using NoSQL).

### The Problem

1. How can I create a global connection with ArangoDB that I can use everywhere else?
2. Will the connection with ArangoDB be active or I need to re-connect?

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of no schema, you **should** create models to work with. Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/pablotcarreira/django-arangodb/blob/master/sample_app/models.py).

Also you have to set similar DATABASES settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'arangodb_driver',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '8529',
        'NAME': 'some_user',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'some_password',
    }
}
```

And to install the driver via:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/pablotcarreira/django-arangodb
```